# e-mail alert set for CRON job on a PHP file?

Tags: php, email, cron, email-validation

I have set a cron-job on a php file. I also set e-mail so that when cron get executed, I am getting e-mail alert. So whatver statement I put in **echo** in that php file that get displayed in the e-mail body.

My doubt is it is not checking code condition , it just flows through code & show echoed statement in the mail body.

Look below code-:

```
$query_update = "UPDATE  tier_price tp 
JOIN   catalog_product_entity cpe   ON    cpe.entity_id = tp.entity_id    
AND    cpe.name LIKE '$col2'   AND   website_id = $col4 
JOIN   customer_group cg   ON    cg.customer_group_id = tp.customer_group_id   AND   cg.customer_group_code =  $col1 SET cpetp.value = ".$col3.";";
mysql_query($query_update);
$count = mysql_affected_rows();
if($count == 1)
{
         echo "<br />"."Price for customer group $col1 for item $col2 is updated to $col3";
}
if($count == 0)
{
       $qry_fetch_product = "SELECT entity_id FROM catalog_product_entity WHERE name = '$col2'";
       $res_qry_fetch_product = mysql_query($qry_fetch_product);
       while($row = mysql_fetch_array($res_qry_fetch_product))
       {
        $entity_id = $row["entity_id"];
       }

       $qry_fetch_grp_code = "SELECT customer_group_id FROM customer_group WHERE customer_group_code = $col1 ";
       $res_qry_fetch = mysql_query($qry_fetch_grp_code);
       while($row = mysql_fetch_array($res_qry_fetch))
       {
        $customer_group_id = $row["customer_group_id"];     
       }

       $qry_insert_base = "INSERT into tier_price(entity_id,customer_group_id,qty,value,website_id) VALUES ($entity_id,$customer_group_id,1,$col3,$col4)";
       $res_qry_insert_base = mysql_query($qry_insert_base);    

  echo "<br />"."Price $col3 for customer group $col1 for item $col2 is inserted";
}
```

The mail alert which I get contains-:

```
<br />Price for customer group 101 for item abc is updated to 252<br />Price 252 for customer group 101 for item abc is inserted
<br />Price for customer group 102 for item pqr is updated to 252.49<br />Price 252.49 for customer group 102 for item pqr is inserted
<br />Price for customer group 103 for item xyz is updated to 15.5<br />Price 15.5 for customer group 103 for item xyz is inserted
```

So my doubt is that, it goes in both loop which should not be the real case. As if query get updated count becomes 1, so it must only go throgh if($count == 1) loop & similarly if no updation count become 0 but from o/p we can see that it is going in both loop & we can see both lines in the e-mail alert which is very confusing...

Can anybody provide solution to avoid this...so that If update happens it show update in mail or insert happens it show insert statement from code..

Comment: What are you expecting to happen? I'm not clear on the exact problem.

Comment: @MattGibson The problem is that apparently `$count == 1 && $count == 0`, which is odd... Although since I don't see this being wrapped in aloop yet the output implies it is, the real problem is anybodies guess. @Prat, please show your full code.

Comment: See, if update statement executed successfully, count will become 1...so it must display-: "Price for customer group 101 for item abc is updated to 252" this statement only. n not this-:"Price 252 for customer group 101 for item abc is inserted " statement as data is just going updated.....But I don't know how cron exacute both echo statement & display the same in e-mail alert....So My doubt is that whether cron didn't check code condition n simply return echod statement into e-mail....I want only update statement in case of count=1 & only insert statement if count = 0

Answer (score 0):

Please check 
http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-affected-rows.php
use something like below

```
<?php
$count = mysql_affected_rows();
if(mysql_affected_rows())
{
}else{

}
?>
```

Comment: Hi Ganesh, How can it will check count=1 condition as we are just providing if(mysql_affected_rows())